# SQLite - How to first insert then update rows inside the database?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

> **Question:** What's the best way to insert values into a database then update values?

I'm relatively new to SQLite, but I'm having trouble changing the values of a row in my database. I've copied and pasted the whole class below:

```
public class Database {

    private final GalaxyCore plugin;
    private Connection connection;

    public Database(GalaxyCore plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Nullable
    public Connection getConnection() {
        File dataFolder = new File(this.plugin.getDataFolder(), "database.db");
        if (!dataFolder.exists()) {
            try {
                if (dataFolder.createNewFile()) {
                    this.plugin.getLogger().info(StringUtil.PREFIX + ChatColor.GREEN + " Successfully created new database folder for storing player information.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            if (this.connection != null && !this.connection.isClosed()) {
                return this.connection;
            }

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dataFolder);
            this.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            return this.connection;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to retrieve database connection", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void loadDatabase() {
        this.connection = this.getConnection();
        try {
            if (this.connection != null) {
                Statement createTableStatement = this.connection.createStatement();
                createTableStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userdata ("
                        + "unique_id MESSAGE_TEXT NOT NULL,"
                        + "receive_alerts INTEGER,"
                        + "receive_pings INTEGER,"
                        + "last_spawn_hat MESSAGE_TEXT NOT NULL"
                        + ");");
                createTableStatement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to load information from database", e);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    public PlayerData readPlayerData(Player player) {
        UUID playerUUID = player.getUniqueId();
        Connection playerConnection;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        try {
            playerConnection = this.getConnection();
            if (playerConnection != null) {
                statement = playerConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE unique_id = '" + playerUUID + "';");
                result = statement.executeQuery();
                if (result.getString("unique_id").equals(playerUUID.toString())) {
                    String name = result.getString("username");
                    int alerts = result.getInt("receive_alerts");
                    boolean receiveAlerts = result.getInt("receive_alerts") == 1;
                    boolean receivePings = result.getInt("receive_pings") == 1;
                    Material spawnHat = Material.getMaterial(result.getString("last_spawn_hat"));

                    PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData(player);
                    playerData.setReceiveAlerts(receiveAlerts);
                    playerData.setReceivePings(receivePings);
                    playerData.setLastSpawnHat(new ItemStack(spawnHat == null ? Material.GLASS : spawnHat));
                    return playerData;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to read player data profile for " + player.getName(), e);
        } finally {
            this.close(statement, result);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void writePlayerData(PlayerData playerData) {
        UUID playerUUID = playerData.getUniqueID();
        Connection playerConnection;
        PreparedStatement statement;
        try {
            playerConnection = this.getConnection();
            if (playerConnection != null) {
                statement = playerConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO userdata(unique_id, receive_alerts, receive_pings, last_spawn_hat) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
                statement.setString(1, playerUUID.toString());
                statement.setInt(2, playerData.isReceiveAlerts() ? 1 : 0);
                statement.setInt(3, playerData.isReceivePings() ? 1 : 0);
                statement.setString(4, playerData.getLastSpawnHat() == null ? Material.GLASS.toString() : playerData.getLastSpawnHat().getType().toString());
                statement.executeUpdate();
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to write player data profile for " + playerData.getName(), e);
        }
    }

    public void close(PreparedStatement statement, ResultSet result) {
        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }

            if (result != null) {
                result.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to close SQLite connection with database", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, the class creates a database that stores a person's unique ID, two booleans for receiving alerts and pings, and the name of the last item they selected (more or less). When I first start up my program, the database works accordingly. If I toggle the `receive_alerts` entry, the value gets updated and saved. However, if I toggle it again and try to save, it doesn't override the original value in the database.

I believe my issue is due to inserting the value, rather than updating the value. However, I'm not sure how to check if a value already exists within a column. I've tried simply google searching, but nothing important comes up.

I was thinking that I could first check to see if a player's `unique_id` is already present in column 1. If it does, then `UPDATE`. If it doesn't, then `INSERT`. But how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this command first -

```
select count(*) from table_name where id=unique_id;
```

If it returns 1, you know it exists, then you can run the update SQL query.

Comment: So I'd put this in `prepareStatement()`?

Comment: Yes, check its result. then issue one more statement to update.

Comment: But how do I check if the ResultSet returns one? My statement is ```PreparedStatement countStatement = playerConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT count(*) FROM userdata WHERE unique_id = '" + playerUUID + "';");``` Is it just ```resultSet.getInt(1)``` to get the first column?

Comment: The answer will only have 1 column as it is select(count)*.
You can do something like this.
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM table_name where id=uniqueid");
r.next();
int count = r.getInt("rowcount") ;
r.close() ;

Comment: this is beyond my intellectual capacity. :P Let me give it a try

Comment: Shouldn't id = uniqueid be replaced with unique_id = <the actual ID of the player>?

Comment: Yeah... not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it's still not updating correctly... I stored `connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM userdata WHERE unique_id = '" + playerUUID + "'")` in a prepared statement and did the execute query on result set. It detects when a player already is in the database, but when I try updating, it doesn't work...

Comment: Right now, it's 5 AM, but I will continue working on it tomorrow.